# How to Delete All Message From Queue In Exchange Server 2007

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, queue

I want to delete all message from Queue. How can I do it with Exchange Server 2007

Answer (score 2):

This powershell command will do it.

```
Get-ExchangeServer | ?{$_.IsHubTransportServer -eq $true} | Get-Queue | 
get-message | Remove-Message -withNDR $false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also open the queue in Exchange Management Console, go to the Toolbox and open the Queue Viewer. Once there, select all messages and click on the Remove option of your choice on the right. (With, or without NDR)

Comment: In Exchange 2010, When I select all messages, the NDR/NoNDR option is removed